# Custom post's taxonomy set to other custom post?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, taxonomy, meta

Is it possible to set/connect first custom post's taxonomy (values) to other custom post?

**Just random and basic example to understand a little better:**

- First custom post: jazz concerts
- Second custom post: places to crash/sleep for night
- Both custom posts has it's own taxonomies and post_metas, for
  example: location, price etc.
- Now we need a connection between posts & taxonomies so that you find most nearest locations to crash if you are going to jazz concert - **that can probably be done by WP_query** & I got this.

I've never seen anything like that in stackoverflow or in WP docs. I tried but it was too long, complicated, didn't make any sense and generated infinite errors & I thought I ask before trying again, maybe someone has been dealing with this kind of situation.

**Do I just need to name taxonomies and post_meta differently and get them to query same way as post's own taxonomy and post_meta? And all same from here?**

**How to get other post's taxonomy/post_meta dropdown box or other types of inputs to admin edit page?**

I hope that I expressed myself clearly. If there's any confusion or questions, let me know & I'll provide additional information or explain something in more depth.

Comment: You can register a taxonomy against several post types: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy in the second parameter of register_taxonomy() you can provide an array of post types. Those post types will then have the same taxonomy.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't pop up in my Google searches. Copy your comment as answer and I'll close the question. That was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Glad to be of help, I have added an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a taxonomy against several post types: [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) in the second parameter of `register_taxonomy()` you can provide an array of post types. Those post types will then have the same taxonomy.